# SQLAlchemy Error in elements.py - ColumnClause nor Comparator has 'description'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The full error is:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'ColumnClause' object nor 'Comparator' object
has an attribute 'description'
```

Occuring at line 544 in sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py in __ repr __

at line 735 in sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py in __ getattr__

I initially discovered the problem because my flask templates, which iterates through the orm `object.__ dict__` to output the data into a table, was not displaying a particular row.

After digging into the python console and importing the module, I produce this error by trying to print the property of the object.

```
from app.models import Parcel
o = Parcel.query.get(1)
o.parcelid #string field prints the correct value, no problem
o.yrbuilt #integer field, same, no problem
o.streetnum #string field, throws above error
```

My model (db variable is `SQLAlchemy(app)`):

```
class Parcel(db.Model):
    """
    the county parcel data
    """
    __tablename__ = 'parcel'
    __table_args__ = {'schema':'gisdata'}
    ogc_fid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True,
        info={'widget': HiddenInput()}
    )
    parcelid = db.Column(db.String(15))
    unit_no = db.Column(db.String(20))
    streetnum = db.column(db.String(100))
    streetname = db.Column(db.String(255))
    city = db.Column(db.String(100))
    mailaddr = db.Column(db.String(255))
    mailcity = db.Column(db.String(100))
    mailstate = db.Column(db.String(5))
    mailzip = db.Column(db.String(20))
    gp_plat = db.Column(db.String(255))
    district = db.Column(db.String(255))
    emv_bldg = db.Column(db.Integer())
    yrbuilt = db.Column(db.Integer())
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Column` should be capitalized, as in:

`streetnum = db.Column(db.String(100))`

:)

Comment: Oh my goodness, of course it had to be something obvious. Thanks for your answer nonetheless!

Comment: I'm surprised python didn't complain that `db.column` isn't a function or some at least some sort of error.

Comment: The Flask-SQLAlchemy `SQLAlchemy` class actually *does* have a `column` property, hence the mystifying error. This is part of the SQLAlchemy API, documented here:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.column